# Cronjob through docker container not running properly

Tags: python, docker, cron

Im trying to setup a cronjob to fire a python script inside a docker container without success.

On my host i have setup a cronjob that should run every day like this:

```
30 10 * * * root docker exec -it container bash -c '/usr/bin/python myscript.py'
```

running the command by itself works fine so nothing wrong with it and in the syslog the cronjob is fired. But the script is not running.

Has anyone come across this before or have any clues as to why the script is not running from cronjob?

Comment: `docker exec` is a way to execute a command inside a **running** container.  
Is your container still running when the cron job is executed?
What error do you get?

Comment: Does cron work with non-docker-commands?

Comment: @zigarn yes the container is running,  i get no errors

Comment: No trace of your cron execution in the cron logs?

Comment: My cron setup logs to syslog, the output is:
CRON[10087]: (root) CMD (   docker exec -it container bash -c '/usr/bin/python myscript.py')

Comment: `-it` is meant for interactive sessions. There's no reason to allocate a tty when running this as a cron job.

Comment: @HåkenLid just found this out myself, that was the problem. removing -it and it works

Comment: Good you got it to work, wanted to add I have had a cron scheduling thing running for about a month now without a problem with a Python package [APSscheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/modules/triggers/cron.html?highlight=cron#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron) inside a Docker container. Can recommend it, but good to know that the docker native cron works.

Answer (score 0):

a blank line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.

```
30 10 * * * root docker exec -it container bash -c '/usr/bin/python myscript.py'
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```